# Sticky div offset from top window using waypoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, offset, sticky

I am hoping someone can kindly help. I'm by no means a programmer, and I'm trying to learn how to create a slightly different sticky div than normal. This is what I want to achieve:

- when the div #projectwrapper scrolls up the screen, and is 150px from the top of the window, it should stick and stay there while the rest of the page scrolls
- when scrolling back down the page, the div should return to its normal place in the page when that comes into view.

I have been trying the demos and examples, and I can nearly get it working. But it will only get activated when it goes to the very top of the window, and it stick at the very top. However I need the activation and sticking to happen 150px from the top.

This is what I have so far.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#projectwrapper').waypoint(function(event, direction) {
}, {
    offset: 150
}).find('#projectdescription').waypoint(function(event, direction){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('sticky', direction === "down");
    event.stopPropagation();
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used waypoint. You can do using some simple jQuery:

```
 var projectWrapperPosition = $('#projectwrapper').position().top; //div position
  $(window).scroll(function() { //when window scrolls
    if($(window).scrollTop() > (projectWrapperPosition - 150)) //check if position of the window is 150px or smaller than the position of specified div has
     $('#projectwrapper').addClass('change-position'); //.change-position position fixed the div
     else
      $('#projectwrapper').removeClass('change-position');

  });
```

css:

```
.change-position {
  top:150px;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  background:red;
}
```

**Check demo:** http://jsbin.com/uxizab/2/ (scroll to see the effect)